# How to write the server side when the client states .ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using a jquery library that rates a training event.  Basically here is the client side code that rates a training date:

```
$('#rateItYours').bind('rated reset', function (e) {
                var ri = $(this);
                var value = ri.rateit('value');
                var trainingID = $("#MainContent_hlTrainingDateID").text();

                //maybe we want to disable voting? ri.rateit('readonly', true);

                $.ajax({
                url: 'RateIt.aspx', //your server side script
                data: { id: trainingID, value: value }, //our data
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                $('#response').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
                },
                error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
                $('#response').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
                }
                });
            });
```

So I've easily got the value of the rating using:

`var value = ri.rateit('value');`

And I also have the Database ID I need for the training date with this:

`var trainingID = $("#MainContent_hlTrainingDateID").text();`

So I can alert both `value` and `trainingID`.  My issue is I never wrote anything that makes some sort of `ajax()` call.  So I see it passes the url `RateIt.aspx` so I created a new webform called RateIt.aspx.  So far so good...but how should the code of this RateIt.aspx intercept the `trainingID` and `value` as noted here:

`data: { id: trainingID, value: value }, //our data`

So I'm using the chrome developers tool, and I see that before I added RateIt.aspx it failed saying it could not find this resource.  So once I created RateIt.aspx then chrome did not report an error, but the issue is I'd like to understand this ajax call and how to write RateIt.aspx.  How would it look to take those values from the `data` line.

Can someone please explain and provide guidance on how RateIt.aspx would look like?  Maybe showing the code (preferably in C#) that actually grabs these values and either alerts them or some sort of mock up code to see I've got the right values?   Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: You need to post to a specific method that expects your id and value parameters in your RateIt.aspx codebehind, e.g. RateIt.aspx/updateRating

Comment: @markpsmith -  I understand that but how would updateRating look based on my post above, that is what I have never done and need help with.

Comment: here's [an example](http://blog.degree.no/2012/03/call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods-using-jquery/)

Comment: @markpsmith that is exactly what I wanted thank you so much, can you please post as an answer and I will accept?

Comment: glad it helped, i've added it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](http://blog.degree.no/2012/03/call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods-using-jquery/), create an updateRating method in your RateIt.aspx page codebehind

```
[WebMethod]
public static string updateRating(string id, string value)
{
   // do something with the parameters

}
```

and call it explicitly in your ajax method

```
url: 'RateIt.aspx/updateRating', //your server side script
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch it with this code

```
var data = Context.Request["data"];
```

then depending on you json format

```
var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var obj = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(data); // or int or object for second argument depending on your data
```

The dictionary would then contain 2 items, one with key id and one with key value each containing one of the values provided.

Comment: I dont understand this, how would this get both the trainingID and the value of the rating?

Comment: I added an example, but markpsmith's solution is probably a cleaner one.